# Click-Once install .NET Framework over and over

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce

The following dialog window keeps popping on my computer when starting "Click-Once" published application from Internet URL:

[Microsoft .NET Framework Setup] - Would you like to download and install the Microsoft .NET Framework?

The content you are trying to access requires the Microsoft .NET Framework. Would you like to download and install this from Microsoft Download Center Now?

....

"Click-Once" starts to work trying to install .NET Framework every time, and even if I run this install it keeps trying to install .NET Framework on subsequent "Click-Once" activations...

I'd expect it should be possible to manually patch some System Registry Entries to fix this issue but I do not know which ones.

Please advise how this issue can be solved.

I know this question has been asked, but no answer as of yet.

Comment: Does the ClickOnce installer actually check if the .NET Framework is installed, or is it always prompting the question and letting the user decide?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see if the install of the .Net Framework 1.1 succeeded?  IF the install fails for some reason on the target machine, it's likely the next run of the ClickOnce app will attempt to re-install.

It's also possible the 1.1 Framework is simply in a bad state.  It may help to remove the framework by hand and let ClickOnce try again on a cleaner state.

- Control Panel
- Add Remove Programs
- Click .Net Framework 1.1
- Select Uninstall

Comment: +1 -- he never said actually installed, just that it was run.  Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a couple "faux-installs" where the user never had enough privileges to install an application, though it did appear to install.  We had to have their sys admin install it with a higher privileged account.